# Using GAPI client apis with Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, google-api-js-client

Actually, my primary goal is to use Google Scripts and Drive APIs in a webpacked Angular4 project. My starting point is this library: https://github.com/rubenCodeforges/angular2-google-api

I am able to authenticate, but I am unable to convince typescript to support `gapi.client.X` APIs.

I have found this definition set, which looks good: https://github.com/Bolisov/typings-gapi. Unfortunately `typings install gapi.client --save` (and all others) yields a big fat error message: *Unable to find "gapi.client" ("npm") in the registry*. And a manual search on the npm page gives no result either. I managed to install them from github source, but only as globals: `typings install github:Bolisov/typings-gapi/gapi.client --global --save`. They appear in the `typings.json` in globalDependencies section. Still, VSCode claims not to know such type definitions.

If this is not the way, how can I teach my VSCode typescript `gapi.client`, `gapi.client.drive` and `gapi.client.script`?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this ?

Comment: @anurag619 no, this project is stalled for now

Comment: I am experimenting with drive api and file permissions. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try install @types/gapi, @types/gapi.auth2 and @types/gapi.client.drive
It worked on my case